# .net framework working version for windows 7 pro build 7600

Tags: windows-7, .net

What version of .net framework work on windows 7 pro build 7600 ? 
And must be offline installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, Windows 7 Build 7600 comes with framework 3.5 but you can download and install Framework 4 from
https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=17718

The next version up Framework 4.5 requires Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

[Build 7600](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/89984-what-build-7600-a.html) means that it's the final version of Windows 7, thus it should be compatible with anything supporting Windows 7 SP1.

The ["Professional" edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions) aspect of your OS won't affect compatibility as it just refers to extra software that was bundled with that release; so again, for compatibility purposes this is just Windows 7 SP1.

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 supports Windows 7 SP1 and has an offline installer.

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 is a highly compatible, in-place
>   update to the Microsoft .NET Framework 4/4.5/4.5.1/4.5.2/4.6/4.6.1.
>   The offline package can be used in situations where the web installer
>   cannot be used due to lack of internet connectivity.

You can download the offline installer and review the installation instructions here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344

Comment: @Swapnil Thanks. If you have a chance, could you award the bounty? :)

Comment: @Swapnil  could you please attach a screen shot of the message and the System Info for your computer? Something funny is going on here. Did you get the matching architecture? 32bit / 64 bit?

Comment: And you downloaded the 64 bit installer? Screenshots?

Comment: Ok thanks. I am on my way to work but will follow up as soon as I can. I am willing to help you live over Skype or TeamViewer later if you want me to